# Jsonp returned from ajax doesn't show on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm calling a page (external, on other domain), with this code:

```
var instagram_container = $('div#instagram-answer');
if (instagram_container.length>0)
{
    var url = 'http://www.xxxx.it/admin/get_instagram_token';
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url,
        async : false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            instagram_container.html(response.client_id);
        },
        error: function(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I have answer with `console.log(e)`  (basically it recognizes as error)?

```
 Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", altri elementi...}
```

But in Firebug, under NET tab, I have the right answer...

[image]

This is the console. Line 19 is exactly the

```
console.log(e);
```

in error section.

[image]

My goal is obtain that Json. Thank you

Comment: You CANNOT set it as async false  `Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.`

Comment: I did set async:false OR removed at all. No answer in console neither in the html.

Comment: What error message do you get? Are you returning valid JSON formatted object?

Comment: NO error. Simply nothing in console && in HTML. In console show object but in the line of error of my script. IN NET tab of firebug you can see the well formed (tested online) JSON.

Comment: Does server accept cross domain request? I'm more familiar with chrome debugging, not sure what kind of error message to expect in FF

Comment: Yes. Could you see the NET image of Firebug posted by me?

Comment: Ya, i can see image but like i said, i'm not familiar with FF debugging.

Comment: If your jsonp is exactly as you've provided in the question, it's invalid. JSONP will never begin with `[` or `{`

Answer (score -1):

Is your server returning plain text, or an actual JSON file? Jquery will ignore the response if the server returned a string instead of JSON.

The response type should be: "application/json"

EDIT:

I'd recommend you to use the basic jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    cache: false
})
.done(function( response ) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Added the header('Content-Type: application/json'); but nothing show in html or in console.